# Python: how to print a string without new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i was bored and made random stuff:

```
rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))
symbol = input("What symbol? (Symbol can only be one.): ")
if len(symbol) > 1:
    print("Symbol length can only be one")

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        print(symbol)
```

But, when i run the code and i made `rows = 5` and `columns = 6` it doesn't work. The result comes like this:

```
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
```

i want to format to:

```
@@@@@@
@@@@@@
@@@@@@
@@@@@@
@@@@@@
```

I even tried `print(symbol, end="")` but the result comes out like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I don't know how or why this happens and i may sound dumb, but this is my first time using nested loops.

Comment: Regarding why it all ends up on one line when you do that: you need to print the newline on each iteration of the outer loop (after the inner one).

Comment: By default, `print()` prints a newline after the contents.

Comment: @RyanM Nope, I tried it and the result comes out as ```@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@``` when i tried ```print(symbol, end="")```

Comment: You need to print a newline _after_ the inner loop finishes.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah thank you. I was struggling. It works perfectly now. Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to move to the next line when you tried `print(symbol, end="")`:

```py
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        print(symbol, end="")
    print()  # <-- missing piece
```

---

However, you could also just use `print(symbol*columns)`:

```py
for i in range(rows):
    print(symbol*columns)
```

---

PS. You also do not abort your script when `len(symbol) > 1`. It will print `Symbol length can only be one` and then just continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
    columns = int(input("How many columns? "))
    symbol = input("What symbol? (Symbol can only be one.): ")
    if len(symbol) > 1:
        print("Symbol length can only be one")

    for i in range(rows):

        for j in range(columns):

            print(symbol, end='')
        print('') # you needed to add this
```